# Code Igniter support for NetBeans 8.0 (OS - Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: codeigniter, netbeans-8

I want to use CI on my Netbeans IDE 8.0 installed on an Ubuntu 14.04. I searched a lot but all methods I found were for earlier versions of Netbeans.  How can I install CI on NetBeans 8.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

http://mansoorin.wordpress.com/2013/05/21/netbeans-7-2-netbeans-7-3-autocomplete-for-ci-2/

Its working in Netbeans8 in Windows8. I'm using it.

Comment: is there any difference between autocompete feature and using a plugin for CI?

Comment: @user2552922 Sorry I didn't understand.